# Dojo dijit layout ContentPane with splitter - programmatically change region orientation

Tags: layout, dojo, splitter, contentpane

I'm using two panes (grid and details) as master-details pattern.
Now I'm trying to create "Details on the right" or "Details on the bottom" toggle button. I do this by changing the region attribut of the ContentPane, like so:

```
function toggleDetails() {
     if(dijit.byId("Details").region == "right") {
        dijit.byId("Details").set("region", "bottom");
        dojo.byId("Details").style.height = "200px";
     }
     else {
         dijit.byId("Details").set("region", "right");
         dojo.byId("Details").style.width = "400px";
     }
     dijit.byId("DetailsParent").resize();
 }
```

The panes themselves are changing fine. **The problem is that I have a splitter for the details pane. When toggling, the splitter is ok for the original orientation, but doesn't render correctly for the alternate orientation.** Any solution to refresh the splitter orientation based on the contentPane region?

I have tried programmatically changing some of splitter widget attributes, like "horizontal" and "region", but nothing really fixed the alternate orientation.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution could be by using removeChild and addChild like in this example

```
        if (isVertical) {

            // vertical layout 

            this.ap_MainContainer.removeChild(this.ap_TopContainer);

            this.ap_TopContainer.region = 'top';

            this.ap_MainContainer.addChild(this.ap_TopContainer);

        } else {

            // horizontal layout

            this.ap_MainContainer.removeChild(this.ap_TopContainer);

            this.ap_TopContainer.region = 'left';

            this.ap_MainContainer.addChild(this.ap_TopContainer);
        }
```